# Find nearest column value from my value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need quick help, can you please?

I need nearest value from the table. I have salary column in my table and it will have values:

```
10000
20000
45000
50000
60000
70000
and so on.
```

And I have one value e.g. 42000. I need to fetch nearest row value of 42000 (if 42000 is in the table, then I want the same 42000.)

Comment: ORDER BY ABS(difference). LIMIT 1.

Comment: please add a schema for us to answer this correctly.

Comment: Sort the Column and follow an approach like binary search.

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tbl_salary ORDER BY ABS( salary - 42000 )

Comment: @roeb, close to my suggestion. But TOP is for SQL Server only.

Comment: Thanks for your Quick help, but what will be value as "difference"  if its 42000 than its show me 10000 :(

Comment: TOP is not working unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the solution :)
and here it is,

```
SELECT *,abs((salary-42000)) as near FROM tbl_salary WHERE order by near limit 0,1
```

Thanks to all who help me anyway.

Answer (score 2):

you need to sort by absolute difference and select the first row.

```
SELECT * FROM salaries ORDER BY ABS(salary - 42000) ASC LIMIT 0,1;
```

But you might think another order or limit clauses because two or more might have the same minimum closest salary.